# Beautiful quotes in documentclass article

Tags: quoting, article

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Inspirational” quote at start of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/inspirational-quote-at-start-of-chapter)

I'm using `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`. How to do this beautiful quote by using `\renewenvironment{quote}` or having my own `\newenvironment{myQuote}`?

[image: Quote]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: No it's not duplicate because this is using article

Comment: It's *very* close, but I'll try to come up with a solution.

Comment: Since this question has been closed as a duplicate, I propose to merge it into the duplicate would, in order to have all the answers in one place, and flagged it accordingly.

Comment: it's not duplicate!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I took Gonzalo Medina's second solution in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53381/510) to ["Inspirational" quote at start of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/inspirational-quote-at-start-of-chapter) and changed the following:

- Instead of using the `memoir` class, the [`epigraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) package (from `memoir`s author) is loaded;
- `\epigraphfontsize` is replaced with `\epigraphsize`;
- The [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package is used to patch the internal `\@epitext` command so that `\itshape` works.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{epigraph}

% \epigraphsize{\small}% Default
\setlength\epigraphwidth{8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}}{\itshape\@epitext{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Graph Theory}

\epigraph{``Begin at the beginning," the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop."}{--- \textup{Lewis Carroll}, Alice in Wonderland}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works so far, but how to do it 100% width, like \begin{quote}...\end{quote} would do it? (I don't need \section btw.)

Comment: @guest453453 I wouldn't redefine the `quote` environment because it might be needed for block quotes in the text body. BTW, `quote` uses a width of somehat less than 100%, and in my example you may change the value of the `\epigraphwidth` length.

Comment: ok lockstep, but how can I do \newenvironment{myQuote} then (or full width like \begin{quote}...\end{quote} would do it if using \epigraph)?

Comment: The `epigraph` package offers an `epigraphs` environment where you write individual quotes using `\qitem`-- have a look at the manual.

Comment: I got it working by doing \setlength\epigraphwidth{16cm}, thanks all.

Comment: @guest453453 You may also use `\setlength\epigraphwidth{\textwidth}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the "work-around" needed for documentclass report as well.