# Problem with space in chapter and quotes

Tags: spacing, quoting

I'm having problems with a ezthesis.

1- This is my fourth chapter and only in this one, my header (Example, Nº4) starts near to the middle of the page, when the other starts near the top.

2- I use the following code (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/inspirational-quote-at-start-of-chapter)) to define my quotes, and in my case, as the images shows, the author appears separated from the quotes, when in the [original example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/inspirational-quote-at-start-of-chapter) is appears on the next line. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,numbers,a4paper,spanish]{ezthesis}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\author{}
\title{}
\degree{}
\supervisor{}
\institution{}
\faculty{}
\department{}
\hyperlinking
\begin{document}
\include{Chapters/titlepage}
\include{Chapters/Ch1}
\include{Chapters/Ch2}
\include{Chapters/Ch3}
\include{Chapters/Ch4}
\include{Chapters/Ch5}
```

And this is my Chapter 4:

```
\makeatletter
%%\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\chapter{Example}

Here is a line before the quotes

\begin{chapquote}{Lewis Carroll, \textit{Alice in Wonderland}}
``Begin at the beginning,'' the King said, gravely, ``and go on till you
come to an end; then stop.''
\end{chapquote}
```

How can I solve this issues?

Thanks in advanced! 
[image: Spacing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not an answer!*. Just to show the importance of MWE (Comment area sucks for codes):

This works:

```
\documentclass[oneside,numbers,a4paper,spanish]{ezthesis}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\author{}
\title{}
\degree{}
\supervisor{}
\institution{}
\faculty{}
\department{}
\hyperlinking

\makeatletter
%%\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
%\chapter{four}
\chapter{Example}

Here is a line before the quotes

\begin{chapquote}{Lewis Carroll, \textit{Alice in Wonderland}}
``Begin at the beginning,'' the King said, gravely, ``and go on till you
come to an end; then stop.''
\end{chapquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Bottom line: Nobody has a crystal ball.

Comment: thanks! I make some changes in text and the quotes adapted themselves. Header chapter is still a little above but I suppose it's better now.