# Width of epigraphs

Tags: rules, epigraphs

How can I set the width of an epigraph for automatic fitting of text inside epigraph?

I would like that the line between text and source have the same width of the above text. This in every epigraph!

Example of what I don't like:

1. Too long a line

   ```
   \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
   \epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are useful.}{George E. P. Box}
   ```

   [image: Too long a line]
2. Too short a line and it adds a new line that I don't like

   ```
   \epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are useful.}{George E. P. Box}
   ```

   [image]

**UPDATE**: the miminal source

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\small}

%\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\textwidth}

\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright} \renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushright}

\let\originalepigraph\epigraph 
\renewcommand\epigraph[2]{\originalepigraph{\textit{#1}}{\textsc{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are useful.}{George E. P. Box}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're not bound to the [`epigraph` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph), then of interest might be [“Inspirational” quote at start of chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/5764).

Comment: [`epigraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) sets `\epigraph` as a set of four rigid-width "`minipage`s". The epigraph (1) text; (2) source; (3) rule and the encompassing epigraph `minipage`. Perhaps an alternative an alternative to `epigraph` would be of interest.

Answer (score 27):

Heavy surgery on the `\epigraph` macro seems to do what you're looking for. With the help of the `varwidth` package we're able to compute the real width of the text (thanks to David Carlisle for the suggestion).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{epigraph,varwidth}

\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\small}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.6\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushright}
% A useful addition
\newcommand{\epitextfont}{\itshape}
\newcommand{\episourcefont}{\scshape}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\epi@textbox}
\newsavebox{\epi@sourcebox}
\newlength\epi@finalwidth
\renewcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
  \vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}
  {\epigraphsize\begin{\epigraphflush}
   \epi@finalwidth=\z@
   \sbox\epi@textbox{%
     \varwidth{\epigraphwidth}
     \begin{\textflush}\epitextfont#1\end{\textflush}
     \endvarwidth
   }%
   \epi@finalwidth=\wd\epi@textbox
   \sbox\epi@sourcebox{%
     \varwidth{\epigraphwidth}
     \begin{\sourceflush}\episourcefont#2\end{\sourceflush}%
     \endvarwidth
   }%
   \ifdim\wd\epi@sourcebox>\epi@finalwidth 
     \epi@finalwidth=\wd\epi@sourcebox
   \fi
   \leavevmode\vbox{
     \hb@xt@\epi@finalwidth{\hfil\box\epi@textbox}
     \vskip1.75ex
     \hrule height \epigraphrule
     \vskip.75ex
     \hb@xt@\epi@finalwidth{\hfil\box\epi@sourcebox}
   }%
   \end{\epigraphflush}
   \vspace{\afterepigraphskip}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are useful.}{George E. P. Box}
\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are usefull.}{George E. P. Box}
\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are usefulll.}{George E. P. Box}
\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are usefullll.}{George E. P. Box}
\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are more useful.}{George E. P. Box}
\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are more and more useful.}{George E. P. Box}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable, egreg! `:)`

Answer (score 14):

If you want each epigraph to be the width of its line, you could just measure the width of the first argument and set the width inside your redefined `epigraph` command. I've loaded the `calc` package to do this easily. Since the measurement of the argument needs to take into account the formatting you set for the epigraph, it's better to use the correct `epigraph` methods for doing this.  So I've created a formatting command which then is used inside a custom environment which is passed to the relevant `epigraph` commands.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\mytextformat}{\itshape\epigraphsize}
\newenvironment{mytext}{\mytextformat}{}
\newenvironment{mysource}{\scshape\hfill}{}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{mytext} 
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{mysource}

\let\originalepigraph\epigraph 
\renewcommand\epigraph[2]%
   {\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{\widthof{\mytextformat#1}}\originalepigraph{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are useful.}{George E. P. Box}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Very easy, but the width of the line is longer than the text.

Comment: @Sigur Fixed in the edited version.

Comment: If I use the new line it doesn't work `\epigraph{All models are wrong,\\ but some are useful.}{George E. P. Box}`

Comment: @tyranitar I can fix the linebreak problem, but getting the rule the right width is a difficult problem to solve if the text is set `\raggedleft` (which is what you need).

Comment: @Alan Munn why?

Comment: @tyranitar The natural width of the text set `\raggedleft` is bigger than the actual length of the line break. So the rule will end up longer than the line.

Answer (score 6):

At the preamble, use this to define a command `\epiline` to use as `\hline` but with other sizes.

```
\newlength\epirule%
\newcommand\epiline{%
\noalign{\global\epirule\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 1pt}\hline%
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\epirule}%
}
```

Here, the command `\epigraph` with two arguments (you don't need the package here).

```
\newcommand\epigraph[2]{%
\hfill\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
{\small\textit{#1}}\\[.5em] \epiline%
{\small\textsc{#2}}
\end{tabular}
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
\epigraph{All models are wrong, but some are useful}{George E.\ P.\ Box}
```

[image]