# Automatically calculate epigraph width

Tags: fonts, width, quotation

I was looking into automaticallly calculating the epigraph width while keeping the epigraph quote left-aligned and non-italic. The following code, copied from a nice solution provided on the page [Width of epigraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96650/width-of-epigraphs), got me pretty far:

```
\usepackage{epigraph,varwidth}

\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\small}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.6\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushright}
% A useful addition
\newcommand{\epitextfont}{\itshape}
\newcommand{\episourcefont}{\scshape}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\epi@textbox}
\newsavebox{\epi@sourcebox}
\newlength\epi@finalwidth
\renewcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
  \vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}
  {\epigraphsize\begin{\epigraphflush}
   \epi@finalwidth=\z@
   \sbox\epi@textbox{%
     \varwidth{\epigraphwidth}
     \begin{\textflush}\epitextfont#1\end{\textflush}
     \endvarwidth
   }%
   \epi@finalwidth=\wd\epi@textbox
   \sbox\epi@sourcebox{%
     \varwidth{\epigraphwidth}
     \begin{\sourceflush}\episourcefont#2\end{\sourceflush}%
     \endvarwidth
   }%
   \ifdim\wd\epi@sourcebox>\epi@finalwidth 
     \epi@finalwidth=\wd\epi@sourcebox
   \fi
   \leavevmode\vbox{
     \hb@xt@\epi@finalwidth{\hfil\box\epi@textbox}
     \vskip1.75ex
     \hrule height \epigraphrule
     \vskip.75ex
     \hb@xt@\epi@finalwidth{\hfil\box\epi@sourcebox}
   }%
   \end{\epigraphflush}
   \vspace{\afterepigraphskip}}}
\makeatother
```

How can I adjust this code to keep the epigraph quote left-aligned and non-italic?

Kind regards,

Jansen

Comment: this seems to be massive amount of code but for non italic just change `\newcommand{\epitextfont}{\itshape}` to `\upshape`  and for flush left change  `\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}`  but I would probably just replace all of this with `\begin{flushright}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}text here with \\ if needed\\ \hline\end{tabular}\end{flushright}`

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example with at least one epigraph?