# how to add a comic strip as a epigraph

Tags: graphics, epigraphs

I'm placing a quote as epigraph of every chapter. But for one i would like to place a calvin and hobbes strip. Which is the best way to do so and keep complaining with the epigraph style?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{epsf,graphicx,subfig} 
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\epigraph{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{calvin.jpg}}{Bill Watterson}
chapter's text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you currently using to produce your epigraphs? There are a number of methods, as you can see from [“Inspirational” quote at start of chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/5764). Perhaps create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) showing your current setup (this should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`).

Comment: I'm using epigraph package and graphicx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, and other than setting the epigraph width, it should work out of the box:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{12cm}
\usepackage{epsf,graphicx,subfig} 
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\epigraph{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{xckd.png}}{Bill Watterson}
chapter's text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Try first with `\documentclass[11pt,demo]{book}` to verify that the problem is not due to not finding the image.

Comment: well with demo it appears a black box. Therefore it the epigraph its working and I've the trouble loading the image. Which puzzles me even more. Because the image is with the rest of the images in the chapter.Pus it does not give any kind of error.

Comment: @sik Can you upload the image somewhere (maybe in your question). First drop in same directory as the .tex file to eliminate path issues.

Comment: The problem was the image, using  `convert` to transform the image to a `.png` file made the trick.