# Align right (hfil) doesn't work for me

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am using TEXShop working at a MAC and I don't really know what I am doing, I am just trying to fill a template. But I want to add something that the template does not offer; align a section to the far right. So I have the following:

```
\chapter{Introduction}

% I need the following to be aligned at the far right
\begin{quote} 
\hfil ``Lorem ipsum dol, \\
\hfil consecteture adipisicing elit.'' \\[1ex]
\hfil John Doe, Lorem\\[1ex]
\end{quote}
% Until here

% And here the normal paragraph begins 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt               
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

But it doesn't really work. Any ideas?

[image: Here's a sample of how it initially looked]

Comment: Remove all those `hfil`s and add `\raggedleft` after `\begin{quote}`.  How about using some dedicated packages for for producing chapter quotes?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It'd be great if you could create a small, complete Minimum Working Example :)

Comment: Thanks! I think it finally works with all the answers below!

Comment: It's seems like you're after something like (possible duplicate): [“Inspirational” quote at start of chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to put some chapter quotes. It is better to use some dedicated packages for this. `epigraph` is one of them.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dol, consecteture adipisicing elit.}{John Doe, Lorem}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily customize things:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dol, consecteture adipisicing elit.}{John Doe, Lorem}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using either `scrbook` or `memoir` they offer the same functionality as built in feature.

Comment: Amazing, it works! Any ideas on how I can make the quote box a little larger? Because if you add a little longer text it doesn't fit each line. Thanks!

Comment: @ddmichael Uae `\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.5\textwidth}` as in updated answer. Change `0.5\textwidth` suitably.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flushright` or `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
\begin{flushright}
``Lorem ipsum dol, \\
consecteture adipisicing elit.'' \\[1ex]
John Doe, Lorem\\[1ex]
\end{flushright}
\end{quote}

\begin{tabular}{r}
``Lorem ipsum dol, \\
consecteture adipisicing elit.'' \\[1ex]
John Doe, Lorem\\[1ex]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: @ddmichael I what sense doesn't it work? The MWE above does produce the image above which seems to be what you asked for?

Comment: It produces the similar output with the one I've quoted above. I just did a copy paste of your code. It is highly probable that I am missing something though as I am fairly new to this.