# How to change the color of the memoir epigraph rule?

Tags: color, memoir

Package [memoir](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) has an `\epigraph` command to typeset [“Inspirational” quote at start of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/30821). While the manual explains how to modify the thickness of **the line** that is drawn **between quote and author**, I cannot find a way to **change its color**. How can it be done?

Minimum non-working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\epigraph{Some inspirational quote}{The Author (1900--2010)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Looking into `memoir.cls` helps ;-)

The command for drawing the rule is `\@epirule`, which is basically nothing different then a wrapper for a standard rule with some width etc. settings. However, there is no color, indeed.

Using a grouped `{\color{yourcolor}\rule...}` (see code below) works. Grouping is necessary, otherwise the color setting would bleed into typesetting and all would be blue, for example.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\epigraphrulecolor}{blue}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@epirule}{{\color{\epigraphrulecolor}\rule[.5ex]{\epigraphwidth}{\epigraphrule}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\epigraph{Some inspirational quote}{The Author (1900--2010)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is just a complement to Christians solution which can be made a bit simpler.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\epigraphrulecolor}{blue}
\makeatletter
\addtodef\@epirule{\color{\epigraphrulecolor}}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\epigraph{Some inspirational quote}{The Author (1900--2010)}
\end{document}
```

We simply prepend the color