# Can I tighten up the white space with this custom fancy chapter code?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, quoting

I found this [lovely formatting code for thesis chapter epigraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/inspirational-quote-at-start-of-chapter/53452#comment663663_53452) posted by @Pluton. I REALLY like how this appears, but it is rather `chunky' and takes up a lot of white space. I also don't like the black bar located below each of the epigraphs. I mean, visually it's just okay but I want everything tighter and cleaner and taking up less space.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I suspected the quotes are so large because of

```
\doublespace
```

I tried wrapping the fancy quotes code in a

```
\begin{singlespacing}
\end{singlespacing}
```

This didn't work.

[Here is a link to the MWE](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/563bb47bdc257a5149b88bb6) but I've also provided most of the code below.

As you can see, lots of white space used by 2 relatively short epigraphs. Code follows screen shots. Title is deliberate taking 2 lines because most of the thesis chapter titles are this long. Help!?!?

[image: Screen Shot Pg 1]

[image: Screen Shot Pg 2]

Packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,
bibencoding=ascii,
citestyle=authoryear,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Next comes code defining the thesis page style and layout. I don't think it's relevant to this question so I've omitted.    It's in the MWE linked above.

```
%%%%%%Begin fancy quotes code below from @Pluton%%%%%%

\definecolor{quotemark}{gray}{0.7}
\makeatletter
\def\fquote{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@i}{\fquote@i[]}%]
           }%
\def\fquote@i[#1]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@ii}{\fquote@ii[]}%]
                 }%
\def\fquote@ii[#1]{%
    \def\tempb{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@iii}{\fquote@iii[]}%]
                      }%
\def\fquote@iii[#1]{%
    \def\tempc{#1}%
    \vspace{1em}%
    \noindent%
    \begin{list}{}{%
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
         \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
                  }%
         \item[]%
         \begin{picture}(0,0)%
         \put(-15,-5){\makebox(0,0){\scalebox{3}{\textcolor{quotemark}{``}}}}%
         \end{picture}%
         \begingroup\itshape}%
 %%%%********************************************************************
 \def\endfquote{%
 \endgroup\par%
 \makebox[0pt][l]{%
 \hspace{0.8\textwidth}%
 \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)%
 \put(15,15){\makebox(0,0){%
 \scalebox{3}{\color{quotemark}''}}}%
 \end{picture}}%
 \ifx\tempa\empty%
 \else%
    \ifx\tempc\empty%
       \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb}%
   \else%
       \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb},\ \tempc%
   \fi\fi\par%
   \vspace{0.5em}%
 \end{list}%
 }%
 \makeatother
```

And here is the rest of the document:

```
\begin{document}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate of Examination}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Co-Authorship Statement}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\Large\begin{center}\textbf{Abstract}\end{center}\normalsize


This is a really silly abstract.

\vfill
\textbf{Keywords:} Time series analysis, data mining
\newpage
\tableofcontents\newpage
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature}
\large List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature \normalsize
\newpage

%Code for making the chapter headings look nice
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\doublespace
\raggedbottom

% Actual chapter content below
\chapter[Short version of the title]{Longer version of the title that I want to make long enough to fit on two lines}
\begin{fquote}[Sarah Jones][Terminal cardiac failure][1901]Lorum ipsum arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristiquesenectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Crasviverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. \nocite{Jones1995}
\end{fquote}
\begin{fquote}[Smith][The Grim Reaper Service][1901] Lorum ipsum arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristiquesenectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Crasviverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\end{fquote}
\section{Background}
\lipsum

\begin{center}
\end{center}


\printbibliography

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\begin{appendices}
\input{AppendixA}

\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First comment: Oh my, this template is ... (fill in yourself ;-))

I made some changes and marked them with `% MY CHANGE` or `MY ADDITION` but I could not address anything there...

- `\singlespacing` is no environment → added the command in the `\fquote` macro
- Added some lengths to provide easier change of the bar height and width
- Removed the bar from the chapter heading (`titleformat`) and put it below the `epigraph`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,
bibencoding=ascii,
citestyle=authoryear,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbibind}  % MY ADDITION
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\makeatletter

%% Define the "thesis" page style.
\if@twoside % If two-sided printing.
\def\ps@thesis{\let\@mkboth\markboth
   \def\@oddfoot{}
   \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
   \def\@oddhead{
      {\sc\rightmark} \hfil \rm\thepage
      }
   \def\@evenhead{
      \rm\thepage \hfil {\sc\leftmark}
      }
   \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      Chapter\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}{}}
   \def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
      \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}
\else % If one-sided printing.
\def\ps@thesis{\let\@mkboth\markboth
   \def\@oddfoot{}
   \def\@oddhead{
      {\sc\rightmark} \hfil \rm\thepage
      }
   \def\chaptermark##1{\markright{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      Chapter\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}}
\fi
\pagestyle{thesis}

% Set up page layout.
\setlength{\textheight}{9in} % Height of the main body of the text
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in} % .5" margin on top of page
\setlength{\headsep}{.5in}  % space between header and top of body
\addtolength{\headsep}{-\headheight} % See The LaTeX Companion, p 85
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}  % space between footer and bottom of body
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} % width of the body of the text
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in} % 1.25" margin on the left for odd pages
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in} % 1.25"  margin on the right for even pages

% Marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{.75in} % width of marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.125in} % space between marginal notes and text

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Number the subsubsections 
\def\normalspacing{1.25} % default line spacing

%%%%%%Begin fancy quotes code below from @Pluton%%%%%%

\definecolor{quotemark}{gray}{0.7}
\makeatletter
\def\fquote{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@i}{\fquote@i[]}%]
           }%
\def\fquote@i[#1]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@ii}{\fquote@ii[]}%]
                 }%
\def\fquote@ii[#1]{%
    \def\tempb{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@iii}{\fquote@iii[]}%]
                      }%
\def\fquote@iii[#1]{%
  \def\tempc{#1}%
  \vspace{1em}%
  \noindent%
  \singlespacing    % MY ADDITION 
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
    }%
  \item[]%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-15,-5){\makebox(0,0){\scalebox{3}{\textcolor{quotemark}{``}}}}%
    \end{picture}%
    \begingroup\itshape}%
  %%%% ********************************************************************
  \def\endfquote{%
    \endgroup\par%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \hspace{0.8\textwidth}%
      \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)%
        \put(15,15){\makebox(0,0){%
            \scalebox{3}{\color{quotemark}''}}}%
      \end{picture}
    }%
 \ifx\tempa\empty%
 \else%
    \ifx\tempc\empty%
       \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb}%
   \else%
       \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb},\ \tempc%
   \fi\fi\par%
   \vspace{0.5em}%
 \end{list}%
 \hfill\rlap{\rule{\chapterbarwidth}{\chapterbarheight}} % MY ADDITION
 }%
 \makeatother

\newlength{\chapterbarheight}
\newlength{\chapterbarwidth}

\setlength{\chapterbarheight}{1cm} % MY ADDITION
\setlength{\chapterbarwidth}{5cm}  % MY ADDITION 

\begin{document}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate of Examination}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Co-Authorship Statement}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\begin{center}
\Large \textbf{Abstract}
\end{center}


This is a really silly abstract.

\vfill
\textbf{Keywords:} Time series analysis, data mining
\newpage
\tableofcontents\newpage
\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature}
\large List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature \normalsize
\newpage

%Code for making the chapter headings look nice




\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{\chapterbarheight}{\thechapter}}% % MY CHANGE
  }%
  {10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\doublespace % Really??? \Doublespace??
\raggedbottom

% Actual chapter content below
\chapter[Short version of the title]{Longer version of the title that I want to make long enough to fit on two lines}
\begin{fquote}[Sarah Jones][Terminal cardiac failure][1901]Lorum ipsum arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristiquesenectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Crasviverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. 
\end{fquote}
\begin{fquote}[Smith][The Grim Reaper Service][1901] Lorum ipsum arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristiquesenectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Crasviverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\end{fquote}
\section{Background}
\lipsum

\begin{center}
\end{center}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\begin{appendices}

\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea loading `txfonts` and then `times`. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: I focused on the main topic --> don't complain about the packages :D

Comment: I'm new at this, @egreg.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, can you explain the comment about \doublespace? I think I added that on my own because the template's original doublespace command wasn't working.

Comment: Also, again, thank you. This worked like a charm in the full dissertation project. You're amazing.

Comment: @AllanM: I personally find the double spacing not appealing visually - my opinion, nothing more, nothing less

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, definitely. It's a requirement for the template :-/