# Inspirational quote editing

Tags: indentation, quoting

I am trying to use the Inspirational Quote that I found in this trend:
["Inspirational" quote at start of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/inspirational-quote-at-start-of-chapter)

Sadly, as I don't have 50 reputation I cannot ask this question in that trend as a comment, so I post it here.

I did some minor changes to the code that is given by the user pluton. Here is my code

```
\definecolor{quotemark}{gray}{0.7}
\makeatletter
\def\fquote{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@i}{\fquote@i[]}%]
           }%
\def\fquote@i[#1]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@ii}{\fquote@ii[]}%]
                 }%
\def\fquote@ii[#1]{%
    \def\tempb{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@iii}{\fquote@iii[]}%]
                      }%
\def\fquote@iii[#1]{%
    \def\tempc{#1}%
    \vspace{1em}%
    \noindent%
    \begin{list}{}{%
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.4\textwidth}%
         \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
                  }%
         \item[]%
         \begin{picture}(0,0)%
         \put(-15,-5){\makebox(0,0){\scalebox{3}{\textcolor{quotemark}{``}}}}%
         \end{picture}%
         \begingroup\itshape}%
 %%%%********************************************************************
 \def\endfquote{%
 \endgroup\par%
 \makebox[0pt][l]{%
 \hspace{0.5\textwidth}%
 \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)%
 \put(15,15){\makebox(0,0){%
 \scalebox{3}{\color{quotemark}''}}}%
 \end{picture}}%
 \ifx\tempa\empty%
 \else%
    \ifx\tempc\empty%
%       \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}
\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb}%
   \else%
%       \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}
\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb},\ \tempc%
   \fi\fi\par%
   \vspace{2.5em}%
 \end{list}%
 }%
 \makeatother
```

If i type this:

```
\begin{fquote}[Macedonio Fern´andez][Museo de la novela de la eterna][1967]\small{Es indudable que las cosas no comienzan, o no comienzan cuando se las inventa. O el mundo fue inventado antiguo.}\end{fquote}
```

The result is something like this:

[image: Inspirational Quote Screenshot]

My question is how do I remove the indentation from the bottom line? I tried adding a \noindent in several lines of the code given above but nothing seems to work. What I want to do is that the line where the name of the author is given is aligned with the quote above it.

Sorry for my English if it is not accurate, I am trying my best.

Thank you very much, Alejandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That indentation is coming from the `\hfill` commands in the line

```
\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb}%
```

and

```
\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\ \emph{\tempb},\ \tempc%
```

Which are trying to set the line aligned to the right. If you remove them, you lose the indentation.