# How to call this or what package is this (picture in post)

Tags: packages, document-classes

[image]
I recently saw a picture of someone in an older post. Does anyone know what package this is or how to call it? I mean the 'Chapter-Beginning', the One over the Chaptername.

Comment: It is probably made with the `epigraph` package.

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53429/138900

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is [quotchap](https://ctan.org/pkg/quotchap) to create the picture in post. I have put a direct link for better details as to write `savequote`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\begin{document}

\begin{savequote}[12mm]
An example
\end{savequote}
\chapter{Quotchap}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would the user that gave a downvote care to motivate that decision?

Comment: I have not understood your comment. I have given a short answer.

Comment: I was trying to refer to the user that gave you a downvote on your answer, I think your answer does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: @Max Ah, I have now understood. Dear Max my English is very limited and I trust you that for almost two years I have been learning with all of you very much. I now receive several downvotes and try not to lament anymore. I get some of them that are unjustified.  I personally do not know what to say to you because I believe that the answer is correct. You could ask **marmot** and certainly on my downvotes it will give you a more precise answer.