# How to change the citation style for one citation

Tags: biblatex, citing

for my bachelor thesis I want to improve my work with a citation in the beginning. How could I do this to make it look like this

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1 : MWE**

Okay this is a MWE which hopefully helps to answear the question. The MWE reference should be look like the one in the image.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,draft=on]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,natbib=true,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Reftester.bib} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}    {0.5em}}
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\hspace*{-\labelsep}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@cite}[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0 cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{6 pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{100}
\begin{document}
"This is a famous reference and should be higlighted as in the picture of this post."  \citet{Mokyr1999}

\printbibliography[ title={7 References}]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2 : Bibtex Entry for MWE**

```
@InBook{Mokyr1999,
chapter   = {The New Economic History and the Industrial Revolution.},
pages     = {1--127},
title     = {The British Industrial Revolution: An Economic Perspective},
publisher = {Boulder: Westview.},
year      = {1999},
author    = {Mokyr, Joel},
editor    = {Mokyr, Joel},
edition   = {2nd. ed.},
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing the link with a screenshot.  Feel free to revert.

Comment: Thanks for that and for the improvement of my english.

Comment: Can you name the style your cite with? If you change values and you only want them to be changed for one part, you can put it in {brackets}. It will only be changed inside the brackets and reverted after them. Can you add a MWE (minimal working example)?

Comment: I cite in APA. I will try to create a MWE and add it to the first post.

Comment: Please don't link to external download sites for parts of the MWE. Instead just paste an example `.bib` entry in the question.

Comment: The Mokyr1999 bib entry is the source of the screenshot shown above, right? However, the quotation shown below the chapter header is a piece by Marx, *not* Mokyr. What are you trying to cite: Marx's *Kapital* or Mokyr's book?

Answer (score 3):

This answer only focusses on the citation aspect of the desired output. For nice formatting of the quotation itself, have a look at ["Inspirational" quote at start of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/35864) and the many linked questions.

It is not entirely clear to me what citations of entry types other than `@inbook` should look like here. I extrapolated, but this *will need* adjustments.

We simply define a new citation command called `\fancyquotecite` that you can use instead of the usual `\cite`, `\textcite`, etc. `\fancyquotecite` is fuelled by the bibliography macro `fancyquotecite` and prints the labelname (the primary name associated with the work/entry, usually the `author` or `editor`) and the titles.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fancyquotecite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{fancyquotecite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro{fancyquotecite}{%
  \printnames[given-family]{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{maintitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{booktitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InBook{Mokyr1999,
  title        = {The New Economic History and the Industrial Revolution},
  pages        = {1--127},
  booktitle    = {The British Industrial Revolution},
  booksubtitle = {An Economic Perspective},
  publisher    = {Westview},
  location     = {Boulder},
  year         = {1999},
  author       = {Mokyr, Joel},
  editor       = {Mokyr, Joel},
  edition      = {2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fancyquotecite{Mokyr1999}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

[image: Joel Mokyr, The British Industrial Revolution, The New Economic History and the Industrial Revolution]

Please note how I changed the contents of some fields in your `.bib` file to work better  with `biblatex`.  Note also that it is a bad idea to include the chapter number in the `title` to `\printbibliography`, use `heading=bibnumbered` instead.

Comment: Ok. Everything you added make sense to me but I can't understand how I can make my quotation look like the one in the image. Maybe my bad english did a good job on that purpose .-.

So my question was/still is how I can create a fancy quotation like the one in the image.

Comment: @mugdi Since you tagged this question with `biblatex` and `citing` and supplied the bibliography and citation MWE I only answered the part of getting the citation/citation call-out produced by `\cite...` or a similar command right. To format the quote itself have a look at the linked question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/35864 and ask a new question (not involving the *citation* part, which I answered) if you have trouble getting it to work. On this site it is better to have questions about one particular issue only and this issue is definitely split in citation and quotation.