# Quotation like with fancychapters but w/o chapter

Tags: quotation

Can I have quotations like with `fancychapters` but without a chapter? I need several quotations for the feedbacks page.

Comment: The short answer is yes.  Just look up the code for fancychapters (I assume it is a package) and copy/modify.

Comment: Depending on the output you want to achive, you might be interested in the `\blockquote` command from the `csquotes` package.

Comment: You don't mean like this, do you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/inspirational-quote-at-start-of-chapter

Answer (score 2):

I know the `fancychap` package, which doesn't show quotes, but I din't know `fancychapters`. However, you might find the `epigraph` package useful which was planned for placing quotations aka epigraphs near sectional divisions, or just to produce a list of them.

```
% quotesprob.tex  SE 576303
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\epigraphhead[60pt]
  {\epigraph{Epigraph before chapter}{Anonymous}}
\epigraph{The whole is more than the sum of the parts}%
         {\textit{Metaphysica} \\ Aristotle}

Now for a list of epigraphs.

\begin{epigraphs}
\qitem{Example is the school of mankind, and they will learn at no other}%
      {\textit{Letters on a Regicide Peace} \\ \textsc{Edmund Burke}}
\qitem{And now for something completely different.}{Monty Python}
\end{epigraphs}

\end{document}
```

[image]